# cast List object to List Long

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have a problem that i can't cast a list of object to a list of Number

```
public List<Long> sommeClassesRep(Choix choix) {

    Query q1xx = em.createQuery("SELECT SUM(h.nb1xx),  SUM(h.nb2xx),SUM(h.nb3xx),SUM(h.nb4xx),SUM(h.nb5xx) FROM HttpEntity h WHERE h.host = :host and h.date_http BETWEEN to_date(:startDate,'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:mi:ss') AND to_date(:endDate,'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:mi:ss')");

    q1xx.setParameter("host",choix.getHost() );
    q1xx.setParameter("startDate", convert.convertDateTime(choix.getStartdate()) );
    q1xx.setParameter("endDate", convert.convertDateTime(choix.getEndDate()));

    List<BigDecimal[]> listSomme = new ArrayList<BigDecimal[]>();
    listSomme =  (List<BigDecimal[]>) q1xx.getResultList();

    List<Long> listSomme =   (List<Long>) q1xx.getResultList();
    List<Long>  listResultat = new ArrayList<Long>();

    for (BigDecimal[]  obj: listSomme ){

        listResultat.add(( obj[0]).longValue());
        listResultat.add(( obj[1]).longValue());
        listResultat.add(( obj[2]).longValue());
        listResultat.add(( obj[3]).longValue());
        listResultat.add(( obj[4]).longValue());
    }

    return listResultat;

}
```

when i debug i show the resulat of the query in the first cell of the list but a sever error that it can't cast an object to a number

help please 
Thanks

Comment: @user3218114 [`Long`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html "java.lang.Long") is a reference type that boxes a primitive `long` value.

Comment: Post the complete stack trace of the exception, and the actual code. What you posted doesn't even compile.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is the exception : SEVERE: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.math.BigDecimal;

Answer (score 3):

The solution would be something like this:

```
public List<Long> sommeClassesRep(Choix choix) {

    Query q1xx = em.createQuery("SELECT SUM(h.nb1xx),  SUM(h.nb2xx),SUM(h.nb3xx),SUM(h.nb4xx),SUM(h.nb5xx) FROM HttpEntity h WHERE h.host = :host and h.date_http BETWEEN to_date(:startDate,'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:mi:ss') AND to_date(:endDate,'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:mi:ss')");

    q1xx.setParameter("host",choix.getHost() );
    q1xx.setParameter("startDate", convert.convertDateTime(choix.getStartdate()) );
    q1xx.setParameter("endDate", convert.convertDateTime(choix.getEndDate()));

    Object[] listSomme = (Object[]) q1xx.getSingleResult();

    Long[] longArr = Arrays.copyOf(listSomme, listSomme.length, Long[].class);
    List<Long> listResultat = Arrays.asList(longArr);

    return listResultat;
}
```

Explanation:

Before start, I do not know what type each value is declared: nb1xx, nb2xx, nb3xx, nb4xx, nb5xx. So for sake of explanation I am assuming all of them to be declared as `Long`.

I changed from `q1xx.getResultList` to `q1xx.getSingleResult` because your query will return only one row.
The row will be an array of objects, so I defined the `listSomme` as `Object[]`.

As you want to return a list of Long, you can create a copy of the Object array to a Long array(assuming they are all of type Long) and then convert the array to a list.

If the sums are not of the type of `Long`(lets say `BigDecimal`), then you could do something like this:

```
Object[] listSomme = (Object[]) q1xx.getSingleResult();

List<Long> listResultat = new ArrayList<Long>();
listResultat.add(((BigDecimal)listSomme[0]).longValue());
listResultat.add(((BigDecimal)listSomme[1]).longValue());
listResultat.add(((BigDecimal)listSomme[2]).longValue());
listResultat.add(((BigDecimal)listSomme[3]).longValue());
listResultat.add(((BigDecimal)listSomme[4]).longValue());

return listResultat;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a few concern:

```
List<BigDecimal[]> listSomme = new ArrayList<BigDecimal[]>();
listSomme =  (List<BigDecimal[]>) q1xx.getResultList();

List<Long> listSomme =   (List<Long>) q1xx.getResultList();
```

You have 2 variables of the same type but with 2 different generic types. Also, why is your query returning a `List<BigDecimal>` and `List<Long>`?

Comment: Thanks Buhake Sindi for your reply, in fact my result query return a list of object so i should cast the type from List<Object> to List<Long>

Comment: Did you resolve your problem? If so, what was the actual issue and how did you resolve it?